# $this->settings empty in Extbase extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

recently I created an extension with the new Extension Builder (TYPO3 6.0, Extbase 6.0). To see if the setup.txt works I added a simple line to it:

```
plugin.tx_myext {
view {
    templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_kremsimpressions.view.templateRootPath}
    partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_kremsimpressions.view.partialRootPath}
    layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_kremsimpressions.view.layoutRootPath}
}
persistence {
    storagePid = {$plugin.tx_kremsimpressions.persistence.storagePid}
}
features {
    # uncomment the following line to enable the new Property Mapper.
    # rewrittenPropertyMapper = 1
}

settings {
    foo = bar
}
}
```

Now I try to get to this in the controller by calling `$this->settings['foo']`. The problem is: The whole settings array is empty. Also I tried {setting.foo} in the fluid template, also empty.

So the simple question is, what am I doing wrong? I wrote on several sites that it should work just like this.

Thnx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the static template of the extension. [See here the tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/sfm_flowgallery/ExtFlowgallery/Configuration/IncludeStaticExtensionTemplate/Index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Did you clear all caches?

Settings for extensions by default are stored in external files, so every change requires clearing whole cache.

Comment: Have you included the extension template in main template? The setup is not loaded automatically.

Comment: O.K, that's a little bit emberassing your right: I forgot to include the static template, it works now.